# class file version is not the same java.version in Eclipse maven

Tags: java, maven

Here is my pom.xml.

As you see , I have the **source/target set as 1.6** in maven compiler plugin . While my project property is set as **java 1.7.**

When i run mvn compile and then check the java class version via javap, i see a **version number =51 which indicate the jre1.7.**

Do i miss anything here  ?

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>        
    <plugins>
```

Comment: check eclipse compiler version.

Comment: @santoshgore, it is 1.7 as i said in the question. The root cause is , when i compile the code in eclipse, i simply use ctrl+s which will invoke the java1.7. since maven use incremental build with version3+, so it will not re-compile the code when i use "mvn compile", while the "mvn clean compile" will work. that is the issue i got .

Comment: First it means you are using the Eclipse Compiler inside Eclipse (by using CTRL-s) and in Maven you use the JDK which is defined by JAVA_HOME which is different (just using source/target is not correct anyway). Furthermore you should use an uptodate version of the maven-compiler-plugin (3.6.1) and not such an ancient version. Apart from that are you starting the Maven build from command line or from Eclipse via Launcher?

Comment: @khmarbaise,  I run the maven from cmd in windows and i know it is using actually a different maven instance (not the same as maven plugin in eclipse) and also the different javac (actually javax.tools.JavaCompiler).  When you say "just using source/target not the correct anyway " can you help elaborate your idea and what is the "expected/correct " way to specify the compiler version  ?